# Increase the NPM Package version automatically

Tags: npm, github-actions, npm-publish, npm-package

I am creating my own NPM packages for the first time. For each commit, 1/ The package version should increase on the NPM registry, 2/ Update the package.json file in the github repository.

.github/workflows/publish.yml

```
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      
env:
  version: 0

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - uses: AutoModality/action-clean@v1
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: 'main'
          fetch-depth: 0
          
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 12
          registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/
          scope: "@nandhirajan-tfi"
      - run: echo "version=$(npm show @nandhirajan-tfi/my-package version)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - run: npm version ${{env.version}} --no-git-tag-version --allow-same-version
      - run: npm install 
      - run: npm build
      - run: npm version patch -m "[RELEASE] %s" --no-git-tag-version --allow-same-version
      - run: npm publish
        env: 
          credentials: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

GitHub Actions Output:
[image]

The above log says that the `npm publish` command has updated the NPM Version to 1.11.18. But the changes are not reflecting on the NPM registry.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to retrieve your `package.json` version. You can use the action [ga-project-version](https://github.com/euberdeveloper/ga-project-version) for that.

Example:

```yaml
name: release

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      # This is how you use the ga-project-version action
      - name: Get version of the project
        id: project-version
        uses: 'euberdeveloper/ga-project-version@main'

      # In this step the exposed version is used as tag of a github release to publish
      - name: Add release
        uses: "marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest"
        with:
          repo_token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          # This is how you access the exposed version
          automatic_release_tag: "${{ steps.project-version.outputs.version }}"
          title: "Deploy"
          files: |
            backend.tar.gz
```

As you can see, you will have the version available in  `"${{ steps.project-version.outputs.version }}"`.
After that the question is with which logic you will augment your version, e.g. the simplest one would be increasing the last number, but it's not a good idea, it'd not be semver.

After that you can use your custom way to get the newer version by using the current one as input ("${{ steps.project-version.outputs.version }}"`).

After having the new version, just edit the `package.json` (e.g. `sed` command) to write the new version, and commit it (e.g. `stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action` action).

In the end you can publish your npm package from the github action (follow [this link](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-nodejs-packages))